# Database error during MODx setup

Tags: modx

Using MAMP/phpMyAdmin on Mac OS X Lion, I'm trying to install MODx on a virtual host. During the process, I encounter this:

[image]

I've been looking around and have as of yet not found anyone with the same problem. The file it claims is missing does in fact exist at that location. Attaching my database setup as well in case it helps. I'd greatly appreciate any help with this, as databases/virtual hosts are very much not my forté.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your login and password correct? MAMP by default uses `root` for each of these. Try that out.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. If I change `localhost` to `painter.dev` (the virtual host where the site resides) I get `Connection refused` as opposed to `No such file or directory`, not sure if that gets me any closer to anything though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a configuration problem.
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Troubleshooting+Installation

If it's not a connection error (that will be found below), I'd suspect that PDO is not installed or active, or that caching (eAccellerator,APC, etc) is interfering.

This is from modx site:

1)
    **You have eAccelerator disabled during install. eAccelerator can cause problems when doing the heavy lifting during the install process.**

2)

PDO Error Messages

If you are getting PDO-related error messages during install, before proceeding to specific error messages as below, please confirm that your PDO configuration is setup correctly. You can do so by running this code (replace user/password/database/host with your setup):

```
< ? php  
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */  
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost';  
$user = 'dbuser';  
$password = 'dbpass';  

try {  
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);  
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();  
}  
? >
```

If this fails, then your PDO setup is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had forgotten to turn off Web Sharing, so somewhere along the way there was a conflict between the two Apache configurations.